# SSIS Data Source select all from table store in variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am working with a SQL Server 2008 R2 BIDS 2008 solution.

I need to transfer data from an Oracle(11g) source database to a SQL Server database. I need to copy all data from multiple tables in the Oracle database.  I have a ForEach container in which there is one Data Flow Task.

I want to loop round a list of table names, select all columns out of  in the Oracle source and copy to dest_ in the SQL Server.

I have added a Property Expression to the Data Flow Task for [ADO NET Source].[SqlCommand] with an expression of "SELECT * FROM " + @[User::ImportPath]

As the table is undefined at this point it isn't clear if I can map columns or setup the ADO NET Destination task correctly.

Is there steps I am missing?  Is what I am attempting to do even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant loop through tables and dinamically map columns on your source and destinations components. You would need one set of Source -> Ddestination per table.

If that's not feasible, you may want to lokk at the [Transfer SQL Server Objects Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142159.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I suspected as much. The Transfer SQL Server Objects Task afaik tell is only for SQL Server -> SQL Server.  Cheers.